# How to call new template in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angular

I have a **directory** component that displays basic content. The page template used by **directory** component is located in projectname/src/index.html. index.html is the default parent template used by all new components.

I created a new **main.html** in projectname/src that is supposed to be used by the new component

**/src/main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

**main/main.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**directory/directory.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-directory',
  templateUrl: './directory.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./directory.component.css']
})
export class DirectoryComponent implements OnInit {

}
```

**src/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyAngularApp</title>
  <base href="/">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**src/main.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyAngularApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**src/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DirectoryComponent } from './directory/directory.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";

import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';

// Each route is an object
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  //{ path: '', component: MainComponent },
  { path: 'homedev', component: HomedevComponent },
  { path: 'directory', component: DirectoryComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
    DirectoryComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What I want to happen is for **main component** to use src/main.html template.

Do you have any idea how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how it works. You cannot replace the root HTML template. That one does not change. What you can do if replace stuff within your `app-root` component in the `index.html`.

If you need to have two separate entry points (html files), I believe you need to create two separate applications and serve them from different folders. But I cannot think of any situation in which you would ever need to do something like this. After all, it is called SPA for a reason...

Comment: I was hoping to achieve a separate template for a basic website and a separate template for a basic system where users can login and check records. is this even possible with just 1 angular 4 app?

Comment: You can use the same root HTML for that. Just style them differently in CSS if you wish to so do.

Comment: okay... i can change the root html in laravel using blade templating